# How to get files from File Share in Storage Account that is in a disabled Student subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-file-share, azure-subscription

I have an Azure Student subscription that I moved from a directory to another, and the billing account still in the first directory.

The problem is that when the subscription reached the limit and was disabled, I cannot reactivate it or upgrade it.

I want to have the subscription back or get a temporary access to the files in the FileShare in order to download the files.

**I tried reactivating or upgrading with the two accounts, and I got the same response**
*You don't have permission to upgrade
You must have an owner role for the billing account. Find a billing account owner at Access control (IAM) and ask them to grant you this role.*

I tried moving the subscription back, but it cannot be moved because it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get access to the files in the disabled Azure Student Subscription.

You have to reactivate it by upgrading the same subscription to Pay-As-You-Go Model.

I can see the similar issue registered in MS Q&A Forum #[938350](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/938350/how-do-i-recover-files-from-a-disabled-student-sub) where the user's requirement is to get the access for the files in Storage account file share on the Azure Student Subscription i.e., disabled and @*DavePatric* had been mentioned the solution to reactivate the subscription for recovering the files.

For reactivation steps and relevant information, refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/azurestudents-subscription-disabled) on Azure Student Subscription.